# Removing 3.5 mm jack socket from a PCB: patching the socket's switches

Tags: pcb, repair, plug, socket

I sheared off a plug from a 3.5 mm headphone jack inside my Roland HP603 piano. After failing to remove the plug, I tried removing the 3.5 mm jack socket from the PCB.

However, the piano still thinks that headphones are plugged in. I think that I need to connect certain pins on the board to fool the piano into realizing the headphones aren't plugged in, but I can't find any circuit diagrams. The jack I removed has 9 pins (not sure why so many, maybe related to 3D sound).

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Not sure about your particular model, but many such headphone jacks have the 3.5 mm plug is what's doing the switching by physically lifting away a NC pin(s) for the internal speaker. Look on the bottom side of the PCB and try to trace out what goes where from the socket. If you removed it, you need to bridge over what was NC before, or replace the connector.

Comment: open the jack that you removed

Comment: Can you share an image of the jack that you removed from PCB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part number for that jack is PJ30150. If I'm looking at the [datasheet](https://www.hy1688.com.tw/SWITCH/DC%20JACK%20HOME/PHONE_File/PJ30150.pdf) correctly, connecting pin 4 to pin 5 and pin 6 to pin 7 should do the job.

[image: PJ30150]

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell from the photo, but you may be able to fix this properly.

My best guess: the missing socket could well be the 9-pin 3.5 mm Jalco YKB21-5344N that Roland often uses. You should check if I identified it correctly. A photo of the missing socket would help, by the way.

You could buy a new one (several suppliers have them) and try to solder it in, or look below for the connection of the switches in the jack socket to make the patch you propose.

[image]
<sup>*Source: Roland FP-10 manual*</sup>

With no plug inserted this socket connects pin 4 to pin 5, and pin 7 to pin 8. You can easily check this with a multimeter if the jack socket you removed is still more or less intact.